# How to add an item into a JSON in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

**EDIT:** I want to be able to add any element into the object, not just specifically age.

Is there any way of adding items into a JSON in Knockout.js?
I want to add age into this existing JSON below and have it reflected on the web page. The click function in my code adds the age onto the JSON but fails to show it on the page.
I have also tried to use cleanNode() + applybindings to re-apply the bindings but the items in the foreach are duplicated

html:

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.name, visible: $data.name !== undefined" ></div>
<div data-bind="text: $data.age, visible: $data.age !== undefined" ></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: children">
  <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
</div>
<button id="button">Test</button>
```

code:

```
json = {
    name: 'Scott',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Alice' },
        { id : 2, name : 'Liv' }
    ]
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS( json );
ko.applyBindings( viewModel, document.body );

document.getElementById( "button" ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
    json.age = "87";
    ko.mapping.fromJS( json, viewModel );
} );
```

fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/f8qbu1j8/6/

Answer (score 0):

Set the age property on the original JSON object, even if you leave it blank. This will cause it to map into your view model properly. Then, later on, you can set the age value on the view model without re-mapping. You should only ever have to use ko.mapping once on an object. See below:

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.name, visible: $data.name !== undefined"></div>
<div data-bind="text: $data.age, visible: $data.age !== undefined"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: children">
  <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
</div>
<button id="button">Test</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var json = {
    name: 'Scott',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Alice' },
        { id : 2, name : 'Liv' }
    ],
    age: null
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({});
ko.mapping.fromJS(json, viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  viewModel.age(87);
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dw1284/nvckyta4/

Answer (score 0):

I approve Dennis's answer. After binding your "viewModel" to the element "document.body", you can change your json by setting the values of "viewModel" :

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.name, visible: $data.name !== undefined"></div>
<div data-bind="text: $data.age, visible: $data.age !== undefined"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: children">
  <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
</div>
<button id="button">Test</button>
```

the javascript part :

```
var json = {
    name: 'Scott',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Alice' },
        { id : 2, name : 'Liv' }
    ],
    age: null
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({});
ko.mapping.fromJS(json, viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  viewModel.age(87); // edit the property "age"
  viewModel.children.push({id : 3, name : 'Adil' }); // add element to the property "children"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time when you are using the `mapping plugin`,it creates a view Model for you based on your object. Since your object does not have an `age` property so you won't have an observable variable for age in your model. Once you update your existing view model with a new Object, it just updates those variables which already have been created before and exist in your model.

Aside from that, since you are using `knockout` you should use the power of knockout and avoid using `jquery` in your model where I can see in your code you are using `Jquery` for `click`event. As you might read the knockout.js documentation, knockout does that for you by using `click` binding.

I assume you are going to have an array of Objects , here is my suggestion how to implement your model so in future it would be easier for you to maintain your model as you might want to add new functionalities to it.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/248/

HTML:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach :Items">
    <div data-bind="text: name, visible:name " ></div>
    <div data-bind="text: age, visible: age" ></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: children">
        <div data-bind="text: name" class="nested"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click:$parent.UpdateAge">Update age to 87</button>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var json = [{
    name: 'Scott',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Alice' },
        { id : 2, name : 'Liv' }
    ],
    age:null
},{
    name: 'Kevin',
    children: [
        { id : 3, name : 'Mike' },
        { id : 4, name : 'Alex' }
    ],
    age:55
}];
var MainViewModel = function (){
    var self = this;
  self.Items = ko.observableArray();
  self.Items($.map(json, function (item) {
    return new ItemViewModel(item);
  }));
    self.UpdateAge = function(item){
    //here you can have your logic to update the age.
    item.age(87);
  }
}
  var ItemViewModel = function (data){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.children = ko.observableArray(data.children);
    self.age = ko.observable(data.age);
  }
 var vm = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```